# Не компилируется проект с библиотекой json-simple

Tags: java, android, json, библиотеки, парсер

При добавлении к проекту библиотеки

```
сom.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
```

выдает ошибку

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Как с этим бороться, подскажите пожалуйста? Проект еще совсем сырой и это единственная сторонняя библиотека.

Вот мой Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ua.com.homeproject.firstproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

}
```

**Обновление**

Добавил `multiDexEnabled` `true`, теперь другое исключение

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>
> > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.class

Comment: Ошибка видимо выше должна быть.

Answer (score 1):

В `defaultConfig` добавьте `multiDexEnabled true`

Answer (score 0):

```
com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
```

На официальной странице нашел только то, что надо качать jar-ник. 
Ваша ошибка возникает при неудачной компиляции через gradle. Иногда изменение версии спасает. а multiDex, насколько я знаю, выставляется, если в проекте используется больше 65к методов. В вашем случае проблема явно не в этом.

Comment: Судя по всему было слишком много библиотек. Для чего и понадобился multiDex

Answer (score 0):

Проект слишком маленький чтобы понадобился multiDex. Почитайте внимательно Event log и Gradle Console при ошибке (вкладки справа внизу в Андроид Студии).

Comment: Проект маленький. а папка libs судя по диагнозу раздутая

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov Я исходил из `Проект еще совсем сырой и это единственная сторонняя библиотека.`

Answer (score 0):

По второй части предлагаю очень внимательно и вдумчиво перебрать содержимое папаки libs. `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

В идеале этот каталог должен стать пустым, а все библиотеки закачиваться как зависимости.

Во втором случае gradle сам разберется с дубликатами.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на каком-то сайте, исправил, теперь компилируется!
Нужно дописать следующее:

```
compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'){exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'}
```